# Android 6 get path to downloaded file

Tags: android-download-manager, android-6.0-marshmallow

I our app (Xamarin C#) we download files from a server. At the end of a succeful download we get the URI to the newly-downloaded file and from the URI we get the file path:

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = downloadManager.GetUriForDownloadedFile(entry.Value);
path = u.EncodedPath;
```

In Android 4.4.2 and in Android 5 the **uri** and **path** look like this:

```
uri="file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/2.zip"
path = u.EncodedPath ="/storage/emulated/0/Download/2.zip"
```

We then use **path** to process the file.
The problem is that in Android 6 (on a real Nexus phone) we get a completely different **uri** and **path**:

```
uri="content://downloads/my_downloads/2802"
path="/my_downloads/2802"
```

This breaks my code by throwing a FileNotFound exception. Note that the downloaded file exists and is in the Downloads folder.
How can I use the URI I get from Android 6 to get the proper file path so I can to the file and process it?

Thank you,
donescamillo@gmail.com

Comment: This was build with SDK 22

Comment: Tried with both SDK 22 and 23, same result

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your actual requirement but it looks like you want to process file content. If so it can be done by reading the file content by using file descriptor of downloaded file. Code snippet as

```
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFd = null;
    try {
        parcelFd = mDownloadManager.openDownloadedFile(downloadId);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(parcelFd.getFileDescriptor());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Error in opening file: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if(parcelFd != null) {
            try {
                parcelFd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

But I am also looking to move or delete that file after processing.

Answer (score 0):

May you an build your URI with the download folder :
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toURI();

Comment: This is what I did, but it works only in Android 5, not Android 6. I found a way around it-I cant get good URI, but I can open the just-downloaded file. So I open the file and copy it wherever I want

Answer (score 0):

It's work. @2016.6.24

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals( action)) {
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterById(downloadId);
        Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);
        if(c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    String downloadFileUrl = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                    startInstall(context, Uri.parse(downloadFileUrl));
                }
            }
            c.close();
        }
    }
}




private boolean startInstall(Context context, Uri uri) {
    if(!new File( uri.getPath()).exists()) {
        System.out.println( " local file has been deleted! ");
        return false;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType( uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    context.startActivity( intent);
    return true;
}
```